# Newbie here - How can I get the text from div class

Tags: python, selenium, get

I am trying to get
1 WAVAX = 9.61353 PNG  ($31.84)
from

```
<div class="sc-bdVaJa KpMoH css-flugrv">1 WAVAX = 9.61353 PNG  ($31.84)</div>
```

With which command should I do it?
I know it's a very easy question but I'm a rookie, and I couldn't find the answer with my little experience.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='sc-bdVaJa KpMoH css-flugrv']")
print(value.text)
```

If that doesn't work we will need much more information in your post, i.e. more HTML, the URL itself, your actual code etc..

Comment: Why not `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.sc-bdVaJa.KpMoH.css-flugrv")` if you're using a CSS selector?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel  That works too.  I am more used to Xpath than CSS myself, so I think that is why I went with the format I did.

Comment: Yes, but with the dotted CSS selector, the classes need not be in any particular order and the element may even have additional classes and the selector would still work.